# Ext GWT 2.2.5 Collapse DatePicker

Tags: java, datepicker, gxt, collapsable

I'm using Ext GWT 2.2.5 in my application.

I want to ask you, is it possible to create DatePicker which can be collapsed and expanded by user click using default framework tools?

Please, see an example below:

[image]

I can not find something like this in the Ext GWT Explorer Demo.
Please, see: http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#datepicker

Thanks, Evgeniy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I created DateAndTimeField class, please see:

```
public class DateAndTimeField extends LayoutContainer {

public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";
public static final String TIME_AND_DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";
public static final String DATE_REGEX = "^\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}$";
public static final String TIME_REGEX = "^\\d{2}:\\d{2}$";
private TextField<String> dateText;
private TextField<String> timeTextField;

public DateAndTimeField() {
    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout();
    tableLayout.setColumns(4);
    tableLayout.setCellSpacing(5);
    this.setLayout(tableLayout);

    this.add(new Label("Date: "));
    this.add(getDateTextField());
    final DatePicker datePicker = getDatePicker();
    this.add(getDatePickerButton(datePicker));
    this.add(datePicker);
    this.add(new Label("Time: "));
    this.add(getTimeTextField());
    this.add(timeTextField);
}

private TextField<String> getTimeTextField() {
    if (timeTextField == null) {
        timeTextField = new TextField<String>();
        timeTextField.setEmptyText("HH:mm");
        timeTextField.setEnabled(false);
        timeTextField.setWidth(100);
        timeTextField.setValidator(new Validator() {
            @Override
            public String validate(Field<?> field, String value) {
                return value.matches(TIME_REGEX) ? null : "not a valid value";
            }
        });
    }
    return timeTextField;
}

private DatePicker getDatePicker() {
    final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
    datePicker.addListener(Events.Select, new Listener<ComponentEvent>() {

        public void handleEvent(ComponentEvent be) {
            String date = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(DATE_FORMAT).format(datePicker.getValue());
            dateText.setValue(date);
            datePicker.hide();
            timeTextField.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
    datePicker.hide();
    return datePicker;
}

private Button getDatePickerButton(final DatePicker datePicker) {
    Button button = new Button();
    button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener<ButtonEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void componentSelected(ButtonEvent buttonEvent) {
            if (datePicker.isVisible()) {
                datePicker.hide();
            } else {
                datePicker.show();
            }
        }
    });
    button.setIcon(GXT.IMAGES.grid_groupBy());
    return button;
}

private TextField<String> getDateTextField() {
    if (dateText == null) {
        dateText = new TextField<String>();
        dateText.setWidth(100);
        dateText.setReadOnly(true);
        dateText.setEmptyText(DATE_FORMAT);
    }
    return dateText;
}

public Date getSelectedDate() {
    if (getDateTextField().getValue().matches(DATE_REGEX)) {
        StringBuilder dateAndTimeText = new StringBuilder(dateText.getValue());
        if (timeTextField.getValue().matches(TIME_REGEX)) {
            dateAndTimeText.append(" ").append(timeTextField.getValue());
        }
        return DateTimeFormat.getFormat(TIME_AND_DATE_FORMAT).parse(dateAndTimeText.toString());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void reset() {
    getDateTextField().clear();
    getTimeTextField().clear();
    getDatePicker().hide();
    getTimeTextField().setEnabled(false);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting your DatePicker in a ContentPanel, and set the panel layout as FitLayout, so the DatePicker would take the panel size.

Then you just need to set the panel as collapsible and its property "hideCollapseTool" to false.

This will show your DatePicker inside the ContentPanel and you will be able to collapse it using the collapse button on the panel's header.

An example:

```
DatePicker miDatePicker = new DatePicker();

ContentPanel miPanel= new ContentPanel();   // new panel

miPanel.setLayout(new FitLayout());         // set layout (so DatePicker resize inside)
miPanel.setAnimCollapse(false);             // set animation (optional)
miPanel.setHeading("Choose a date");        // set a header text          
miPanel.setCollapsible(true);               // allow panel to collapse
miPanel.setHideCollapseTool(false);         // show the collapse button
miPanel.setBorders(true);                   // show border of panel

miPanel.add(miDatePicker);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Seems to be interesting solution, but I need to see what date is selected when datePicker is collapsed. Please, see the approach I proposed

Comment: Your approach is very good too. I believe creating your own "customized component" is allways the best way to go. Great!! Sadly I've just started at Stackoverflow and can't Vote Up your answer yet. See you around!